# Glossaries set Custom font for Table of Acronyms and Glossary

Tags: fonts, luatex, glossaries, acronyms

I want to print a Glossary and Abbrevation/Acronym page with the Glossaries package. But I am needed to use a custom (company internal) font for the label and description of both.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\newacronym{te}{Test}{Test Test}
\newacronym{foo}{FooBar}{Foo Bar Foo Bar}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

    Using the \gls{foo}. Using \gls{foo} again.

    Using the \gls{te}. Using \gls{te} again.   

\end{document}
```

I need to change the marked text to `\myfont`:
[image]

How do I set `\myfont` for Each of the marked for the Acronyms and Glossary?
I do not want the `\gls` to be changed to a diffrent font.

Comment: Just as an aside: use either `babel` or `polygossia`, but not both. And with xetex or luatex `fontenc` and `inputenc` must not be loaded.

Comment: Thanks Javier, didn't know that. I am still pretty new to Latex